# Hi, I have a problem with React Native Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I did everything as in the instructions on the website https://rnfirebase.io/
But when the application starts, an error crashes image

[image]

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
>
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1. imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
> 2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
>
> See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database'


export default function MainPage() {
    const reference = database().ref('/dialogs');
    console.log(reference)
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainPage}>
         <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

My file MainApplication.java

```java
package noorsoftMobile.com;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import noorsoftMobile.com.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("noorsoftMobile.com.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^12.7.3",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "noorsoft-intership-development-version-mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: So did you follow the instructions? Have you done the twot htings?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have made many attempts

Comment: Cool cool cool. Can you show any of them? What does your `MainApplication.java` file look like?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, I added it above

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using v5 of the react-native-firebase package. Can you check your package.json and see if this is the case?

From your error message it says you need to modify your MainApplication.java file, which is required for firebase/database in [v5](https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/database/android) of the library but not in [v6](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage) according to the docs.

So if you are in v5, you can follow [migrating to v6](https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6) from the library docs.

Comment: I added package json to the question itself

Comment: @Peoples Can you also include your both build.gradle files and settings.gradle?

Comment: my projects  https://github.com/MRXOneX/noorsoft-mobile  almost clean

Comment: @Peoples Found it. Try removing these two lines at "app/build.gradle". 
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
Then, run gradle clean (https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6#cleaning-gradle)